# How to ignore the ffff and ensure the padding of 0 for single byte?

Tags: java, byte

I have the following which I have read and I know that my checkcode is for sure to be only single byte value but when I convert I tend to get ffffff9e etc. But I need only 9e. How can I convert it to just have purely 2 digit and with padding of 0 if its single digit ?

```
                byte checkCode = r.readByte();             // check code
      System.out.println("checkCode is 0x: " + Integer.toHexString(checkCode));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact is, if you convert 0x9e to a int number, it will be -98, and the `ffffff` indicate the `minus symbole -`. There are 6 `f` because you are using `Integer`, try `Long` and you will get more `f`.

If you got another test data, for example, 1e (which is 30 in int value), then the result will be as your expectation.

If you just want to remove the `f`, most simple way:

```
System.out.println("checkCode is 0x: " + Integer.toHexString(checkCode).substring(6, 8));
```

Because you are using `Integer` so you always want the substring from 6 to 8.

Comment: If you are using Integer.toHexString, always 8, try Long.toHexString you will get more f.

Comment: So the best just to use Integet to hex then ?

Comment: It depends my friend. 9e is quite a small number, if your data is too large that Integer can not express, then use Long.

Comment: Actually i am very new to this byte and integer stuff. So byte is the basic right ?

Comment: byte is the shortest. Sorry I forgot your data is always in byte, if this is true, then Integer is always enough.